# Is there any way to improve my dancing ability?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I went to the Purgatory bar to hang out with Jeff and EDI and decided to loosen up a little and dance, but it just seems like Shepard just stands there and shifts weight between his feet or walks in place.

This is pretty lame.

I also tried having a few drinks before dancing, but I usually just end up blacking out and waking up next to Aria.

Is there any way to make Shepard dance better with alcohol, upgraded skills, or does his Paragon/Renegade rating have anything to do with it?

Comment: Jack actually comments that everybody knows Shepard can't dance and I don't think Shepard has time to take dancing lessons, with the universe being under attack... :P

Comment: I don't think anything affects it. I also tried drinking. Femshep sounds like she's a *slightly* better dancer, but not by much.

Comment: FemShep does wave her arms in the air (like she just don't care) briefly as well as shuffling from foot to foot, does that count as better dancing? (I can't tell, having my formative years at the tail end of the rave scene means that quickly shuffling your weight side to side while waving your arms in the air Is dancing as far as I know it!)

Comment: Shepard dances bad in an ironic way.

Comment: Male Shephard does a slightly better dance at Purgatory before you run off on many missions.  I went there before meeting Aria, and near the back wall- top floor was a spot that let me dance.  Not much better mind you, but it wasn't the zombie shuffle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shepard's lack of dancing ability is a running gag in the ME series in general.  Several characters comment on it.

No, there is no way to make Shepard a better dancer.